# Passando parametros de campo data

Tags: c#

Estou com  um problema até simples de resolver, mas como sou novato em C# não estou conseguindo a solução.

Tenho dois form, form 1 tenho dos txtBox que coloco a data inicial e data final, e este form 1 tenho um botão de imprimir qual chama o from 2 já com os campos data inicial e data final preenchidos, só que quando estou chamando o form 2 esta dando o erro de exceção baixo.

> Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" em System.Data.dll
>
> Informações adicionais: The conversion of a varchar data type to a
>   datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Segue código (apenas parte relevante) do form 1

```
private string conm = @"Data Source=192.168.0.250;Initial Catalog=DADOSADV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=SQL";

SqlConnection conexao = null;
SqlCommand comando = null;


private void ListaGrid()
{
    string strSQL = @"SELECT
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SC.C5_EMISSAO AS DATE), 103) AS [EMISSÃO PED.],
                      SC.C5_NUM AS PEDIDO,
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SF.F2_EMISSAO AS DATE), 103) AS [EMISSÃO NF.],
                      SC.C5_NOTA AS NF,
                      SC.C5_XCLIDES AS CLIENTE,
                      SC.C5_VOLUME1 AS VOLUME,
                      S4.A4_NOME AS TRANSPORTADORA
                   FROM SC5020 AS SC
                   INNER JOIN SF2020 AS SF WITH (NOLOCK) ON SF.F2_DOC = SC.C5_NOTA
                   INNER JOIN SA4020 AS S4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON S4.A4_COD = SC.C5_TRANSP
                   WHERE SC.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SC.C5_NOTA <> ''
                   AND SF.F2_EMISSAO BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'" + txtDtInicial.Text +"', 103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'"+ txtDtFinal.Text +"', 103) ORDER BY SF.F2_EMISSAO";

    conexao = new SqlConnection(conm);
    comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conexao);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
        dados.Fill(dtLista);

        dgPedidoDiario.DataSource = dtLista;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmImpPedidoDiario pedido = new frmImpPedidoDiario(txtDtInicial.Text, txtDtFinal.Text);
    pedido.Show();
}
```

segue código form 2

```
public partial class frmImpPedidoDiario : Form
{
    public frmImpPedidoDiario(string INICIAL, string FINAL )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtDtInicial.Text = INICIAL;
        txtDtFinal.Text = FINAL;
    }

    private void frmImpPedidoDiario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtDe, dtAte;
        DateTime.TryParse(txtDtInicial.Text, out dtDe);
        DateTime.TryParse(txtDtFinal.Text, out dtAte);

        this.PedidoDiarioPSTableAdapter.Fill_PedDiario(this.DSPedidoDiario.PedidoDiarioPS, dtDe.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), dtAte.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));

        this.rpwPedidoDiario.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: Favor postar o erro que aparace na imagem aqui como texto, dessa forma facilita muito a vida das pessoas que poderão te ajudar

Comment: Ok desculpe vou fazer a correção

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo de `txtDtInicial.Text` no momento do erro?

Comment: 01/04/2017 este e o conteúdo que estou passando no form 1

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Uma dica sobre o uso do site: tente ser menos prolixo ao postar seu código. Ou seja, poste apenas as partes relevantes, que realmente podem fazer alguma diferença para identificação do problema. E também é sempre importante lembrar: a formatação é muito importante.

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro E qual é o valor no outro `TextBox`???

Comment: uma data inicial e outra data final Ex. 01/04/2017  e 18/04/2017

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Por que você removeu a única parte do código que era realmente relevante?

Comment: Desculpe sou novo em c#, achei que a parte relevante no form 1 fosse a parte que eu chamo o form 2, que não esta aparecendo no código acima no form 1

Comment: Claro que não, o erro é um `SqlException`, provavelmente o problema é justamente a `query`.

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Qual é o formato dos valores das colunas `SC.C5_EMISSAO` e `SF.F2_EMISSAO`.

Comment: então estas colunas da tabela e tudo varchar

Comment: Isso eu sei, eu quero saber qual o formato DOS VALORES. Me dê um exemplo de um valor que está salvo numa destas colunas.

Comment: no select e desta forma 20170401 e como mostro acima eu converto para este formato 01/04/2017, não sei se e isto que vc quer saber.....

Comment: É isso mesmo. A linha que estoura o erro é aquela `this.PedidoDiarioPSTableAdapter.Fill_PedDiario [...]`??

Comment: Correto e este linha mesmo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, tente não montar a consulta concatenando os parâmetros, mesmo que não haja o risco de `SQL Injection`, porém o SQL Server não vai conseguir guardar o plano de execução da consulta.

Segundo ponto, `using` é seu amigo e deve ser utilizado sempre que o objeto implementar a interface `IDisposable`.

terceiro ponto, evite fazer conversões desnecessárias no `SqlServer`, retorne o DateTime e trate direto no `C#`.

Segue um exemplo com as alterações sugeridas.:

```
string strSQL = @"
    SELECT
        CAST(SC.C5_EMISSAO AS DATE) AS [EMISSÃO PED.],
        SC.C5_NUM AS PEDIDO,
        CAST(SF.F2_EMISSAO AS DATE) AS [EMISSÃO NF.],
        SC.C5_NOTA AS NF,
        SC.C5_XCLIDES AS CLIENTE,
        SC.C5_VOLUME1 AS VOLUME,
        S4.A4_NOME AS TRANSPORTADORA
    FROM SC5020 AS SC
    INNER JOIN SF2020 AS SF WITH (NOLOCK) ON SF.F2_DOC = SC.C5_NOTA
    INNER JOIN SA4020 AS S4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON S4.A4_COD = SC.C5_TRANSP
    WHERE SC.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SC.C5_NOTA <> ''
    AND SF.F2_EMISSAO BETWEEN @DataInicial AND @DataFinal ORDER BY SF.F2_EMISSAO"; 

try
{
    using (conexao = new SqlConnection(conm))
    {
        conexao.Open();
        using (comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conexao))
        {
            var dataInicial = DateTime.Min;
            var dataFinal = DateTime.Max;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDtInicial.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dataInicial);
            DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDtFinal.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dataFinal);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataInicial", dataInicial);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFinal", dataFinal);

            using (var dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando))
            {
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);
                dgPedidoDiario.DataSource = dtLista;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo as alterações acima, quando fiz as alterações meu datagrid parou de funcionar não achando mais da datas.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos.